# creating .sh file to execute visual studio 2010 project

Tags: c#, shell, project

I have a question: how can I create a .sh file to execute a visual studio 2010 console project in C#? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean running a bash-script? I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1804818)

```
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "/tmp/bash.sh";
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    psi.Arguments = "test";
    Process p = Process.Start(psi);
    string strOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(strOutput);
}
```

Comment: :)) i am trying to do the opposite, a shellscript that executes a compiled visual studio in c# project

Comment: I that case I don't understand the question: a compiled VS project is an executable whydo you need a script to execute an executable file?

Comment: dunno why...I have the exe's